# How do I convert 3 int rgb values into one int value of color in android studio?

Tags: java, android, colors, rgb

I don't know how to convert my 3 values (int value for `red`, `green` and `blue`) to one color int value at android.

Answer (score 0):

Color (android.graphics.Color) is an default android class.

```
int myColor = Color.rgb(red, blue, green)
myView.setBackgroundColor(myColor);
```